# Yii2-Kartik DataPicker disable the previous dates on the calendar

Tags: php, datepicker, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, active-form

I am using Kartik datepicker in yii2 and I want to disable the previous dates on the calendar to avoid picking them.

Here's my code:

```
DatePicker::widget([
'model'=>$model,
'attribute'=>'datetime_range',
'name' => 'from_date',
'value' => '01-Feb-1996',
'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
'name2' => 'to_date',
'value2' => '27-Feb-1996',
'pluginOptions' => [
'autoclose'=>true,
'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy',
'todayHighlight' => true,
'startDate' => date("yyyy-MM-dd H:i:s"),
]
]);
```

Comment: this is fine .. it will disable previous dates from today.

Comment: you have to mention 'startDate' option which you have done. What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: I don't quite find an option to disable previous days... but you can add in backend a limit from which day user's select is valid.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas: How to add in backend that limit?

Comment: If it's fine, I can post this solution as an answer. Not 100% about what you asked but still restricts choices.

Comment: Your question is that of many. Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 3):

Set date picker plugin option

```
'startDate' => date("Y-m-d")
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't forbid user from picking up passed days, but it will display an error when doing so. What you need to do, is to add an additional rule to `rules()` method in **model**:

```
[['date'], 'date', 'min' => time(), 'minString' => date('d-m-Y'), 'format' => 'php:d-m-Y']
```

The first word `date` is your attribute (probably `from_date`?).

Comment: No, I want to disable previous date for example today is 8/06/2016 i want to disable 7/06/2016 to all past dates